# QML tutorial: Directory is not a type

Tags: qt, qml

I'm learning QML by Qt examples. However I have a problem like this:

```
file:///home/lion/Documents/qtquick1-dev/examples/declarative/tutorials/gettingStarted/core/fileMenu.qml:62:5: Directory is not a type 
         Directory { 
         ^
```

The code is checkout [**here**](https://github.com/qtproject/qtquick1/tree/dev/examples/declarative/tutorials/gettingStarted). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which version of Qt are you running and how did you install it?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969518/qml-object-type-is-not-a-type-error-in-qtcreator

Comment: @SimonWarta: I use Qt 4.8.5 with QtQuick 1.1

Comment: @user2672165: Is it a name conflict? AFAIK QML don't have a definition for type `Directory`. And it's an official example of Qt, it should work out of the box :(

Comment: If you're learning Qt, I'd go straight for Qt 5

Comment: Is this a missing import in fileMenu.qml? Could you try adding something like `import FileDialog 1.0`. I guess the name of the plugin is the name of the import, but I am not sure about that.